# Could my previous numpy calculations go wrong silently if its tests fail?

Tags: python, numpy, testing

I can use numpy on my machine without problems. But after running `numpy.test('full')` I got the following errors. Should I be concerned that something is actually wrong silently in my previous numpy calculations?

```
opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/random/tests/test_generator_mt19937.py:1214: AssertionError
============================================================== warnings summary ==============================================================
opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/tests/test_fft.py::TestFFT1D::test_dtype
  /Users/zhfu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/tests/test_fft.py:51: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
    a = a.astype(t1)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
1 failed, 9028 passed, 555 skipped, 18 xfailed, 3 xpassed, 1 warning in 287.18s (0:04:47)
```